# Converting NVARCHAR TO INT

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, type-conversion, conventions, menubar

The column data type is `NVARCHAR(MAX)`. How can I convert it to `Integer`?

```
CREATE TABLE UsrMast(Usr_Id int,
                     Usr_Pswd varchar(30), 
                     Usr_Priv varchar(100))

CREATE TABLE T117_MenuMst(MenuID int,
                          Text varchar(50),
                          Description varchar(200),
                          ParentID int, 
                          NavigateUrl varchar(100))
```

Stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_MENUITEM (@UserID [varchar](50))

BEGIN 

    CREATE TABLE #TMP(MenuID INT, Text VARCHAR(50), Description VARCHAR(50), ParentID INT, NavigateUrl VARCHAR(100))
    DECLARE @VAL NVARCHAR(MAX), @Pos INT, @len INT
    --SET @VAL=(SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), SUM(CAST(PrivilegeID AS NUMERIC(30, 0)))), '2', '1'), '3', '1') FROM tblGroupPrivMst WHERE GroupCode in (SELECT GroupCode FROM tblUserGrpMap WHERE UserID=@UserID))
    SET @VAL=(SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(70), SUM(CAST(Usr_Priv AS NUMERIC(38, 0)))), '2', '1'), '3', '1') FROM T112_UsrMast WHERE Usr_Id=@UserID)
    SET @Pos=1
    SET @len=LEN(@VAL)
    WHILE(@len!=0)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Value CHAR(1)
        SET @Value=SUBSTRING(@VAL, @Pos, 1)
        IF @Value=1
        BEGIN
            PRINT @Value
            INSERT INTO #TMP SELECT * FROM T117_MenuMst WHERE MenuID=@Pos
        END
        SET @Pos=@Pos+1
        SET @len=@len-1
    END
    --For first Node (Inserting The Parent Node)
    INSERT INTO #TMP SELECT * FROM T117_MenuMst WHERE MenuID IN(SELECT DISTINCT ParentID        FROM #TMP WHERE ParentID NOT IN(SELECT MenuID FROM #TMP))
    --For second Node (Inserting The Parent Node)
    INSERT INTO #TMP SELECT * FROM T117_MenuMst WHERE MenuID IN(SELECT DISTINCT ParentID        FROM #TMP WHERE ParentID NOT IN(SELECT MenuID FROM #TMP))
    --For third Node (Inserting The Parent Node)
    INSERT INTO #TMP SELECT * FROM T117_MenuMst WHERE MenuID IN(SELECT DISTINCT ParentID        FROM #TMP WHERE ParentID NOT IN(SELECT MenuID FROM #TMP))

    SELECT * FROM #TMP ORDER BY MenuID ASC
    DROP TABLE #TMP
END
```

But I'm getting:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric.

In `UsrMast` table `Usr_Priv` value is

```
10101111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

Please help me.

Comment: ***What database system*** and which version is this for??

Comment: In most database system, the **maximum** value for `INT` is 2'147'483'648 (just over two billion). Your string is **way too BIG** for an `INT`! And that's **exactly** what the error is saying...

Comment: I AM USING SQLSERVER 2008R2, N my error is exactly "Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric."

Comment: Usr_priv is for storing user Privileges, actually i am having more than 60 menu items in my project. Previously it was 32 items only. the above query is working upto 38 i.e ( the length(usr_priv) = 38.////usr_priv='10101111111111111111111111111111111111 for 38 Char's).

Comment: That number is **way too big** as an `INT` ! You cannot convert that to an INT -

Comment: This is myrequirement                                                                CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T112_UsrMast](
 [Usr_Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [Usr_Pswd] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
 [Usr_Priv] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL)

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestion, i tried but at the time on executing the stored procedure i am getting the error. But if i reduce the total char's in that number it was executing with our errors. actually in my stored procedure i am converting from navarvhar to numeric. is there any other way to convert or is there any other way for modifying my stored porcedure.

Answer (score 0):

You can only store Up to this value in the Numeric Data Type :

Maximum Length value you can store is upto 38 but your data is (10101111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111) 50 character numeric value. So, no way...

Take a look at this:

- decimal [ (p[ ,s] )] and numeric[ (p[ ,s] )] : 
  Fixed precision and scale numbers. When maximum precision is used, valid values are from - 10^38 +1 through 10^38 - 1.
- bigint : 
  Integer (whole number) data from -2^63 (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808) through 2^63-1 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807). Storage size is 8 bytes.
- int : 
  Integer (whole number) data from -2^31 (-2,147,483,648) through 2^31 - 1 (2,147,483,647). Storage size is 4 bytes. The SQL-92 synonym for int is integer.
- smallint : 
  Integer data from -2^15 (-32,768) through 2^15 - 1 (32,767). Storage size is 2 bytes.
- tinyint :
  Integer data from 0 through 255. Storage size is 1 byte.